# Calling jquery function in jsfiddle with no libraries set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I am trying to call a jquery function from html, but it seems that it's not working.  I have my jsfiddle page set to pure js (no libraries being loaded for me) as I am trying to load them in html myself.  Any ideas why this function isn't being called?  If I set the jquery library in jsfiddle, then it works.

jsfiddle.net/qD6PN/

p.s.
The reason I don't want to load the library in through the jsfiddle UI is because I am trying to figure out why my script isn't being called correctly in MVC, so I don't want jsfiddle to do anything special.

Thanks!

Comment: it works: http://jsfiddle.net/qD6PN/1/

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Barlas, but as I mentioned, I wanted to avoid loading the jquery library through the jsfiddle UI and I want to know how to do this by loading jquery via the html tab.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, JSFiddle will put everything in the HTML section into the `<body>` of your HTML document (it's not meant to have a `<head>` as near as I can tell). You *can* put a `<script>` tag in the HTML but it will be loaded *after* anything in the Javascript pane, which is placed in the actual `<head>` produced by the JSFiddle.

If having JSFiddle wrap your HTML and code in its own tags makes your test case problematic, you can try [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) which includes libraries exactly the way you are doing in this fiddle, by adding `script` tags to the `head`.

Comment: As I'm sure you can tell, I am very new to jquery/javascript.  I was under the impression that if I just declare the src={jquery lib} I can call any jquery functions.  Or maybe I am misunderstanding how objects get constructed in javascript.  Would you be able to give me a boost on how this should be setup to call this function?  Thank you Plynx!

Comment: @user518043 Sure, added more explanation above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out how jsfiddle wraps the code Plynx.  I tried jsbin as you suggested and everything works as expected.  Thanks again!